# Issue with jQuery / iframe File Uploading Solution

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, uploading

I recently implemented a jQuery / iframe solution to file uploading and have run into a rather annoying issue (only in IE of course).

Upon clicking my upload button and selecting a file to upload, I automatically submit the form that contains the file to my iframe. However - I am required to click anywhere on the page in order for the submit to process and fire the action in my Controller.

I believe it is an issue with the iframe gaining focus, which seems to be stopping the 'change' function from finishing execution, but I am not entirely sure. Perhaps some type of onload function is required for the iframe to kick the focus back to the original page to continue execution?

**Code:**

**Form & File Upload:**

```
<form id="attachForm" action="<%= Url.Action("TestUpload","Images") %>" 
      method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" target='upload_target' >
        <input id='actualupload' type='file' multiple="" name='file' />
</form>
<iframe id='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='' 
        style="width:0; height: 0; border: 0;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**jQuery to Submit Form:**

```
$("#actualupload").live('change',function()
{
    $("#attachForm").submit();
    alert("Fired!"); //This only occurs after clicking on the screen after the 
                     //file selection.
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `.live()` causes this strange behavior. If you use i.e.

```
$(function() {
    $("#actualupload").change( function()
    {
        $("#attachForm").submit();
        alert("Fired!"); //This only occurs after clicking on the screen after the 
                         //file selection.
    });
});
```

it works in IE too.